# magento 2 admin page not working with custom store view

Tags: magento2

I have multi language store and the default one is **Portuguese**, when I access admin page with other store view the page gives **404** page not found, but when I access with default store view it works properly. How can I access admin page with other store views

Comment: admin-page with another store-view? I think you're mixing stuff up.

Comment: i have two store views one is Portuguese and other is french. when i access my website eg. www.magento2.com the default store is portuguese, when i enter www.magento2.com/admin it works properly. but when i go to www.magento2.com and change the store view to french when i re-enter www.magento2.com/admin the page gives me 404 page not found

Comment: that's an explanation you should have put in the question. this is indeed not the expected behavior!

Comment: i just i created other store view and it works, The problem is with French store, i guess i messed up with the configuration of this specific store